# Use bind variables inside pl/sql stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Is it possible to use bind variables,(declared and initialized outside pl/sql block) inside pl/sql stored procedure

I am just trying to print bind variable defined as shown below :

**Bind variable declaration and initialization**

```
var jdata varchar2(4000);
exec :jdata := ''{"PONumber":12,"Reference":"StackOver"}'';
```

**pl/sql procedure**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE generic_procedure( v_typename IN VARCHAR2,v_path IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '$') IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(:jdata);
END generic_procedure;
/
```

**Error**

> fails at compilation:
>       SQL> show errors
>       Errors for PROCEDURE GENERIC_PROCEDURE:
>
> ERROR: bad bind variable 'JDATA'

Here, I'm trying to call jdata inside generic_procedure(stored pl/sql procedure) . but it says JDATA as

> bad bind variable

Comment: You pass values into a procedure through the parameter list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a substitution variable:

```
define jdata='{"PONumber":12,"Reference":"StackOver"}';


create or replace PROCEDURE generic_procedure( v_typename IN VARCHAR2,
                                               v_path IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '$') IS
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line('&jdata');
END generic_procedure;
/
```

But you can also pass it as a parameter to the procedure. Which seems a bit cleaner to me. Since the procedure does not depend on some variable that has, or has not been, declared outside of it. It just works on the parameters alone.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE generic_procedure( v_data IN varchar2,
                                               v_typename IN VARCHAR2,
                                               v_path IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '$') IS
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line(v_data);
END generic_procedure;
/

exec generic_procedure('&jdata','typename');
```

[Here's](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables) some more about variables in sqlplus

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, don't think this is possible as the PL/SQL variables need to be defined in the scope of the package or procedure.

You can create a package to hold this variable and then set and use it's value in the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE P_test 
is 
 jdata CONSTANT varchar2(4000):=''{"PONumber":12,"Reference":"StackOver"}'';
END P_test ;

create or replace PROCEDURE generic_procedure( v_typename IN VARCHAR2,v_path 
 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '$') IS

BEGIN

 dbms_output.put_line(P_test.jdata);
END generic_procedure;
```

Hope it helps
Vishad